# Access Facebooks signed_request on localhost

Tags: facebook, iframe

I'm a little confused, that this problem is not mentioned anywhere:

I'm developing an iFrame App for a facebook fanpage and want to access signed request from localhost.

I've visited and tested most of the available stackoverflow threads and other forums - without success.

I'm not even sure if it's possible at all!

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

[Develop Facebook Application on Local Host](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-develop-your-facebook-application-locally/6/) will help you easily

Comment: @chp edit your question and post your code that you are using

Comment: @chp The code used was out-dated. I just edited it to reflect the new PHP, and JS SDKs. I'm planning to extend the tutorial soon!

Comment: Thanks for updating your tut. I will revisit your site then.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a virtual host which reflects the same parent domain name (for example while creating the facebook application, if your domain name is xyz.com - then create a virtual host with dev.xyz.com or something like that) and runs from your localhost.

Now you can use FB JS-SDK to collect tokens and use that token in other graph API calls without any problem at all!!

Comment: Ah, sorry. I don't get it. What do you mean by virtual localhost that runs from localhost? Thanks!